# Arabic Spell Checker API

Tags: spell-checking, arabic

I searched about spell checker API from google but the arabic language is not supported there if any one can help me to find the AP that support arabic language or any other good idea.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK none of Google's spell check APIs are documented/supported, and as such they could break at any time.

It is possible to spell check using the Google translate api:

`http://translate.google.com/translate_a/t?client=t&text=كيف حاك&sc=1`

Returns:

```
[[["كيف حاك","كيف حاك","",""]],,"ar",,,,,["كيف \u003cb\u003e\u003ci\u003eحالك\u003c/i\u003e\u003c/b\u003e","كيف حالك"],[],33]
```

Scroll to the right and you'll see the corrected results `كيف حالك` at the end.

The `sc=1` parameter includes the spell check in the results. You'll have to figure out how to parse the JSON results  to get the corrected spelling,

Answer (score 0):

You could try this one:

`https://github.com/Arabic-Spell-Checker/spellchecker-api-client`

It has a REST API and provides dictionary management functionalities.

Disclaimer: I am the developer of this.

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline.